# Invalid docker-compose after import from .env file, string needed

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I defined the following docker-compose

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
      - MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      - MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      - MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD}
    ports: 
      - 3306:3306/tcp
```

In the same folder I got the following .env file:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
MYSQL_USER_PASSWORD=test
MYSQL_USER=admin
MYSQL_DATABASE=test
APP_CUSTOMER_NAME=test
APP_CUSTOMER_ID=123
APP_SETTINGS_DECIMAL=,
APP_SETTINGS_THOUSAND=.
```

when doing docker-compose config I get: services.db.environment contains {"MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD": "test"}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string

Apparently the file gets parsed but I don't get the error message at all. AFAIK I followed the docker manual, or I a missing a stupid small thing. Thank you!

Comment: use `=` instead of `:` in envs

Comment: Oh yeah, that works, thanks. Is this valid yaml, or is docker doing this, to parse the variable properly?

Comment: yes this is a valid yaml